# Java doesn't work (IcedTea )

Tags: firefox, java, openjdk, icedtea

I installed IcedTea Plugin on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS using Firefox.

I receive this error message:

> Problem initializing runtime environment. Changing the SecurityManager is not allowed.

I am not very technical, so my 12-year old son will handle this. I need someone to help me in easy terms. 
this is the output:
(The output contains links so I cant post. Please give reputation at least 10.)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you open terminal, run this command `apt-cache policy icedtea-7-plugin openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jre-headless` then [edit] the question and add the command output.

Comment: The output is not too long. Could you append it to the question text. I will fix the formatting.